# How to get chat in pop up

Tags: html

I am using zoho for live chat in my website. How to get that pop up which usually comes in most of the website

its code is some thing like this...

```
   <div style="height:300px; width:300px; padding-top:20px;"><iframe style='overflow:hidden;width:100%;height:100%;' frameborder='0' border='0' src='http://chat.zoho.com/mychat.sas?U=c36599f3bbee3974d1af8b95ee04001b&chaturl=helpdesk&V=********************Center&smiley=false'></iframe></div>
```

How to make sure that this iframe must be loaded in a pop up..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the complete solution that worked for me

HTML CODE:--- chat.html contains the code i got from zoho...

```
Click<a href="chat.html"  style="padding-left:0px;"rel="popup console 350 350">here</a> to chat with us
```

this is the main thing to be noticed...

```
rel="popup console 350 350"
```

Javascript code...

```
function addEvent(elm, evType, fn, useCapture){if(elm.addEventListener){elm.addEventListener(evType, fn, useCapture);return true;}else if (elm.attachEvent){var r = elm.attachEvent('on' + evType, fn);return r;}else{elm['on' + evType] = fn;}}


var newWindow = null;

function closeWin(){
if (newWindow != null){
    if(!newWindow.closed)
        newWindow.close();
}
}

function popUpWin(url, type, strWidth, strHeight){

closeWin();

type = type.toLowerCase();

if (type == "fullscreen"){
    strWidth = screen.availWidth;
    strHeight = screen.availHeight;
}
var tools="";
if (type == "standard") tools = "resizable,toolbar=yes,location=yes,scrollbars=yes,menubar=yes,width="+strWidth+",height="+strHeight+",top=0,left=0";
if (type == "console" || type == "fullscreen") tools = "resizable,toolbar=no,location=no,scrollbars=no,width="+strWidth+",height="+strHeight+",left=0,top=0";
newWindow = window.open(url, 'newWin', tools);
newWindow.focus();
}

function doPopUp(e)
{
 //set defaults - if nothing in rel attrib, these will be used
var t = "standard";
  var w = "780";
 var h = "580";
 //look for parameters
  attribs = this.rel.split(" ");
 if (attribs[1]!=null) {t = attribs[1];}
  if (attribs[2]!=null) {w = attribs[2];}
  if (attribs[3]!=null) {h = attribs[3];}
  //call the popup script
  popUpWin(this.href,t,w,h);
  //cancel the default link action if pop-up activated
  if (window.event) 
    {
window.event.returnValue = false;
window.event.cancelBubble = true;
} 
  else if (e) 
{
e.stopPropagation();
e.preventDefault();
}
  }

  function findPopUps()
   {
   var popups = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
   for (i=0;i<popups.length;i++)
{
if (popups[i].rel.indexOf("popup")!=-1)
    {
    // attach popup behaviour
    popups[i].onclick = doPopUp;
    // add popup indicator
    if (popups[i].rel.indexOf("noicon")==-1)
        {
        popups[i].style.backgroundImage = "url(pop-up.gif)";
        popups[i].style.backgroundPosition = "0 center";
        popups[i].style.backgroundRepeat = "no-repeat";
        popups[i].style.paddingLeft = "3px";
        }
    // add info to title attribute to alert fact that it's a pop-up window
    popups[i].title = popups[i].title + " [Opens in pop-up window]";
    }
}
  }

  addEvent(window, 'load', findPopUps, false);
```

Answer (score 2):

try using window.open

```
window.open("http://chat.zoho.com/mychat.sas?U=c36599f3bbee3974d1af8b95ee04001b&chaturl=helpdesk&V=********************Center&smiley=false","mywindow","location=1,status=1,scrollbars=1,width=100,height=150");
```

Answer (score 0):

Add page onLoad event to popup.

```
<body onLoad="window.open('http://chat.zoho.com/mychat.sas?U=c36599f3bbee3974d1af8b95ee04001b&chaturl=helpdesk&V=********************Center&smiley=false','mywindow','location=1,status=1,scrollbars=1,width=100,height=150');">
```

`

Comment: This will be zapped by every popup blocker out there. Don't use window.open except in response to user triggered events.